# Is the following condition enough for differentiability?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, functions, derivatives, partial-derivative

If the partial derivatives of a field $\psi(x,y,z)$ always exists at point $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ even if we rotate the Cartesian coordinate system in any angle, then can we say $\psi(x,y,z)$ is differentiable at $(x_0, y_0,z_0)$?

Comment: No, that's not enough. The standard example of a function that has partial derivatives along all directions, but is not differentiable, will do to disprove this claim.

Answer (score 0):

No, for example:
$$
\psi(x,y,z)=\left(\frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^2},\frac{xz^2}{x^2+z^2},\frac{yx^2}{x^2+z^2}\right)
$$
Has a partial derivative in every direction, but is not differentiable on (0,0,0).

Comment: What if I ask it this way "If the partial derivatives of a field $\psi(x,y,z)$ always exists at points near $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ even if we rotate the Cartesian coordinate system in any angle, then can we say $\psi(x,y,z)$ is differentiable at $(x_0, y_0,z_0)$?"

Comment: My example still holds. The partial derivatives exist everywhere (we define the field to be zero at the origin).

Answer (score 0):

No. You also need the partials to be continuous. *Then* the function is differentiable.